# Pandas : Add a column of arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do something that (I think), should be pretty simple.

I have a DataFrame `df` and an array of String `tags`:

```
>> print(df)
        Field1    Field2       
0           AA        10       
1           BB        20       
2           CC        30 
3           DD        40


>> print(tags)
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
```

I want to add in `df` a new column 'Tags' that contains the array of String `tags`.

```
>> print(df_out)
        Field1    Field2                       Tags     
0           AA        10   ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'] 
1           BB        20   ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']    
2           CC        30   ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
3           DD        40   ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
```

Note : In this example the same array is used for each row. In my real use case it will be differents arrays with different lengths.

But most of the thing I tried ended up with the error message :

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: "I want to add in df a new column 'Tags' that contains the array of String tags".. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
df['Tags'] = [tags for x in df.index]
print (df)
  Field1  Field2                Tags
0     AA      10  [tag1, tag2, tag3]
1     BB      20  [tag1, tag2, tag3]
2     CC      30  [tag1, tag2, tag3]
3     DD      40  [tag1, tag2, tag3]
```

> In this example the same array is used for each row. In my real use case it will be differents arrays with different lengths.

Is necessary create nested list of all values with same length like length of DataFrame:

```
tags = [['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'], ['tag2', 'tag3'], ['tag3'], ['tag3']]
df['Tags'] = tags
print (df)
  Field1  Field2                Tags
0     AA      10  [tag1, tag2, tag3]
1     BB      20        [tag2, tag3]
2     CC      30              [tag3]
3     DD      40              [tag3]
```

Comment: This solution work well, but I am not sure to understand why `df['Tags'] = [tags for x in df.index]` is needed (instead of `df['Tags'] = tags `)

Comment: @Nakeuh - First repeat same value (nested lists are created by list comprehension), second add nested lists with different length or different values - cannot be used first solution.

Comment: Yes, but the thing I don't really understand is why `df['example'] = "example"` will correctly add the string 'example' to each row of the dataframe, and in the case of an array we have to use the list comprehension to have a similar behavior.

Comment: @Nakeuh - Reason in my opinion why  lists are handled different should be performance, but not 100% sure.